# Android In-app Billing - IMarketBillingService.java not being generated

Tags: android, in-app-billing, aidl

I have a project with in-app billing implemented. It's currently on
the market, and everything is working fine. Now that I wanted to make a new build for an update, things went upside down.
I had cleaned my project and the `ImarketBillingService.java` file doesn't get generated anymore. Things that I've tried:

- refresh, clean, reimport a million times
- checking/unchecking project builders
- re-adding the IMarketBillingService.aidl file to my project
- building for other API levels
- adding the generated java file from an older version of my project (signing went okay, but after I've installed the apk on a device, the app immediately crashed because it couldn't find the necessary files for billing service)

Comment: Do you still have the problem? Is the aidl file on the right location in your app? "com.android.vending.billing"

Comment: Hey dude..any luck with this issue..??? If yes .. post the solution as answer...

Comment: I'm also having this issue after updating my eclipse/android SDK to latest version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for me here:
[Android Pre Compiler error on 21.0.1 android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188650/android-pre-compiler-error-on-21-0-1-android-sdk)

There is an issue with the Android SDK tools 21.0.1 pre-compiler. It seems to have issues with .svn folders causing the pre-compile stage to fail, preventing the processing of the IMarketBillingService.aidl file. This link has a couple of workarounds for it.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was this instruction

`If you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment: Create the following directory /src/com/android/vending/billing and copy the IInAppBillingService.aidl file into this directory.`

even though I am using Eclipse Juno, this was after installing the adt-preview and android tools-preview, none of which solved the problem.

You just have to follow the non-eclipse instructions because everything is messed up right now