# Android Building Workspace Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, workspace, android-storm

I have a project that uses [stORM](https://code.google.com/p/storm-gen/). When i try to open Eclipse downloaded as a Android ADT package. i am getting the following error

[image]

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'stORM'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have noticed that if i delete this project from the Workspace Eclipse works fine. Looks like there is some issues with the Annotation Processor of stORM or ADT package.

Any idea how to solve this ?

ADT version

[image]

Comment: Is the project named stORM here your demo project? How did you create it?

Comment: @DavidChandler yeah here the name of the problem is stORM. but i have tried it with different names. still the same. I think its got to do something with the ADT Kit package. Tried on a second machine which using eclipse with adt installed on top of it - it works fine. When i restart the IDE this problem occurs

Comment: Which version of Eclipse & ADT are you using?

Comment: @DavidChandler v21.0.1-543035 updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Thanks, Harsha. I haven't tried the ADT bundle, only the ADT plugin for Eclipse. I'll see if I can reproduce it with the ADT bundle for Windows.

Comment: @DavidChandler it works fine with the ADT plugin. I jumped from the ADT bundle since it had lot out errors anyway. Thanks for the Lib. Loving it otherwise.

Comment: It happens to me as well, with my own projects, I am starting a bounty for the question, it doesn't generate R file, unless I do project clean, but the error still shown.

Comment: @meh download the ADT plugin and use it with Eclipse. it works fine. ADT Bundle seem to have a look of bugs in general as well. It doesnt delete refactored projects as well :P

Comment: @Harsha M V: I am using Juno Eclipse, and the normal ADT and it still happens.
If I re-import the project then the problem is gone, but only until I start eclipse again. argh ...

Comment: @meh it works fine for me with Juno :(

Comment: Did you try to download the storm jar file again? maybe the download was corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this issue upgrading the SDK Manager and ADT to the latest preview versions.  See here for more information:

[Android Pre Compiler error on 21.0.1 android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188650/android-pre-compiler-error-on-21-0-1-android-sdk)

Answer (score 5):

WORKAROUND

Hi there! I've been getting the exact same error (latest ADT plugin (21.0.1-543035) and Eclipse 4.2.1).

What helps in my case: I turn off annotation processing in "Project Properties/Java Compiler/Annotation Processing", then restart Eclipse, Clean Project, re-enable annotation processing, Build.

Comment: yeah i got that happening. But most of the times we forget to turn it off :P