# AndroidPreCompiler build error after updating Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

After updating my Android sdk tools to v21.0.1 I keep getting the AndroidPreCompiler build error with a NullPointerException on every project. I can create a new project no problem but once i add in the files from the broken project it causes this error and none of my projects build.

Does anyone know why this would be? Maybe a problem with the latest sdk tools?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Posting error details, e.g. stack trace wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Please cut/paste an example error message/stack trace?

Comment: what error u r getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've once had exact same issue and it turned out to be related to this question: [Android Pre Compiler error on 21.0.1 android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188650/android-pre-compiler-error-on-21-0-1-android-sdk)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327874/1820695) posted there:

> The Android Pre Compiler in 21.0.1 appears to be badly broken, crashing on .svn directories and .DS_Store files, and files without file extensions.

was the reason in my case. Try updating to the newer ADT if possible.

Comment: Spot on. That was it! Also this helped: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051