# Error when using new versions of Development Tools, etc in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have an app for already over 1 year and so far there was no problem at all to compile it.
The app uses kankan wheel http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/list

The last working development environment is shown in `N`ew and always yields this error

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Pre
>   Compiler' on project 'myProject'. java.lang.NullPointerException

while the environment shown in `O`ld works without problems.

I do not have any idea whatsover why I get this compile error with the new development environment. But it is clear that one of the new 4 Android updates is causing it. As soon as I let the Old version update to the new I get the error again. So I can't update my Eclipse anymore :-(

I tried everything I could think of like updating the `.Metadata` file, reinitializing any library links, changing used Android SDK version, including/excluding Android Dependencies, but all to no avail.

What could cause this new compile problem, or better what do I have to do so I can use the new development tools again ?

[image]

This is my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms768m
-Xmx1224m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to check the `eclipse.ini` file for the `-Xms`, could be related to that? There's a lot of hits on **optimizing eclipse** that may help resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I am not sure I understand. I added my eclipse.ini above, what do you mean with "hits on optimizing eclipse that may help resolve it"?

Comment: May be the project has activated the Annotation Processing. See Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Annotation Processing, and compare it with you old Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer here: [AndroidPreCompiler build error after updating Android SDK Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14363806/1820695).

I'm pretty sure that's the reason.

Comment: I installed SVN now, but when I compile I get the same error - do I need to do anything else or should this already really have solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: It does not concern only SVN. It crashes also for files without extension. You have to either downgrade your ADT version or upgrade SDK Manager and ADT from preview channel: http://tools.android.com/preview-channel

Comment: I already had the newest version, however it updated anyway and in fact that solved the issue - thank you very much, wasted a complete day since I thought I changed something accidentally and retrieving all the different subversions....

Comment: @user387184 glad you resolved this! anyway, have a good week :)