# Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'XXXXXX'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have three projects in two different Workspace in same computer.

**MainProject**

**google-paly-servies-library**

**pdf-view library**

I have used GCM in my main project. And both libraries projects added in main project as library project.
In one workspace this project working fine. But in second workspace I got following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'Project Name'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Because of this error I got **cannot be resolved** error in all GCM related code:
E.g

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;
```

I have android sdk tools **25.0.5 (Preview)**

ADT plugin **23.0.6**

Eclipse **Mars**

I also got few answers regarding this issue:

[Eclipse / Android : "Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project)

[Android Pre Compiler error on 21.0.1 android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188650/android-pre-compiler-error-on-21-0-1-android-sdk)

But not working for me. Same projects working in different workspace (that in **c: drive** and I copied these project in second workspace in **d: drive** where I got this error).

I can't understand what happens after changing workspace.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Rebuild project" or restart the eclipse.
 Check imports and check other folder instade c:/ .
I had the same erros because of the c:/ folder, permissions...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already tried "Rebuild project" or restart eclipse many times. In case of permissions, what kind of permissions issue you face in c:\? Although in my case c:\ workspace is working, problem in d:\.